# How to dynamically change the draw-order of geotiff rasters in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, mosaic, vrt, gdalbuildvrt, draw-order

In ArcGIS it is possible, via raster mosaics, to choose the raster order depending on various methods. One such method is the center method. The raster that is closest to the coordinate of the center of the current view is on top of all other rasters. This is great when one has a case of superposition of equally sized rasters.

Unfortunately I am not finding any way to do this with QGIS. I've looked at VRTs (virtual raster mosaics, I don't know what the T is for), but they don't seem to have an ordering option.

Any ideas?